# Can we use epsilon-net method on an open set?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Let $X_{t\in T}$ be a random function where $T$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Since $T$ has inifite points, we are not able to use union bound to estimate $\sup X_t$. Thus instead, when $T$ is compact (then the covering number of $T<+\infty$), we could use $\epsilon$-net argument to derive a meaningful upper bound on $P(\sup X_t\geq\cdots)\leq$.

However in my case, $T$ is a rectangle with one open line, i.e. $[0,1]^n\times (0,1]$. I was wondering could we use $\epsilon$-net in this case?

Many thanks for suggestions!

Comment: What is $\mathbb{P}(sup$ ... Please be more explicit. What do you know about $(X_t)_{t \in A}$? And what is an $\epsilon$-net argument?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. $P(\sup f\geq \epsilon)$ is the probability that the supreme of a random function larger than the value $\epsilon$. $X_t$ is a general random process. $\epsilon$-net argument is a method to derive estimation on $\sup$ of random process over a set with infinite points.

Comment: It will depend on the process because it could be that $X_{t}$ diverges at the boundary not included in $T$. If you have a specific process in mind, we can try to see if some modification of chaining or some other method will apply.